# Is it possible to use maven shade plugin to relocate a library that uses native methods?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to use maven-shade-plugin to relocate a library. Unfortunately, this library also includes some native implementation.

The problem I'm facing is that after relocation to a different package, when trying to call the native methods from that library, I get [UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html).

I guess the problem arises because of [how native method names are resolved](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp615) (the java counterpart has a different package after relocation).

Is there any known way around this?

Comment: Create an adapter library that will redirect functions with new names to the original library. Alternatively call JNI [RegisterNatives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#RegisterNatives) to manually bind Java native methods to the functions from the original library.

Comment: thanks, your solution will work; however it has the disadvantage that any changes to the API of the native library might result in UnsatisfiedLinkError